# how to make child list stay open after onmouseout of parent and give it the function to hidden after onmouseout of itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    const el = document.getElementById('iitem1');
    const hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('rrow1');
    
    // ✅ Show hidden DIV on hover
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function handleMouseOver() {
      hiddenDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
    });
    //keep the hidden Div till mouse is out
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function handleMouseOut() {
  hiddenDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
 });
  
  hiddenDiv.onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
function mouseOut() {
  hiddenDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

this is my code, I had an item with a row which opens in front of it. I did it with mouseover and mouse out functions but the problem is when I mouse out the item I want the row remains still in order to make me able to move mouse over the list I created in the row section.

Comment: `});` missing start match for it

Comment: Please show a proper [mre] when asking question like this - without seeing the HTML this is supposed to work on, we don't really know what is going on.

Comment: to present the html makes it long, I want to know why the js code does not work? and as I explained there is menu in which I have a parent item and a child row which contain a list in it. when i hover the parent Item appears when I mouse out it is still there but I cannot mouse over the child list